# Cannot fetch data from mlab using local express.js

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mlab

I've tried to fetch mLab from express.js on my local. Node was compiled correctly, but when I access mLab using mongoose, console shows 500 error. Error object in callback was also null.

router/index.js

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();

var post = require('../models/post');

/* GET home page. */
router.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
    post.getAllPosts(function(err){
        if(err) throw err;
        res.render('index', {posts : posts} );
    },3);
});

module.exports = router;
```

models/post.js

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');

//Post Schema
var PostSchema = mongoose.Schema({
    title : {
        type: String
    },
    body : {
        type: String
    },
    category:{
        type:String
    },
    date: {
        type:Date
    },
    author:{
        type:String 
    },
    mainimage:{
        type:String
    }
});

var Post = module.exports = mongoose.model("Post", PostSchema);

//get all post
module.exports.getAllPosts = function(callback){
    Post.findOne(callback);
}
```

and then this is mLab collection schema

```
{
    "_id": {
        "$oid": ""
    },
    "title": "test1",
    "body": "test body",
    "category": "test categ",
    "date": {
        "$date": "2017-01-24T16:24:23.187Z"
    },
    "author": "author",
    "mainimage": "testimg"
}
```

console.log right after access / route

```
my-MacBook-Air: $ node app.js
GET / 500 353.624 ms - 5709
GET /vendor/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css 304 3.488 ms - -
GET /stylesheets/clean-blog.min.css 304 10.164 ms - -
GET /vendor/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css 304 9.533 ms - -
GET /vendor/jquery/jquery.js 304 8.806 ms - -
GET /vendor/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js 304 8.019 ms - -
GET /js/jqBootstrapValidation.js 304 6.361 ms - -
GET /js/contact_me.js 304 5.368 ms - -
GET /js/clean-blog.min.js 304 2.721 ms - -
GET /images/home-bg.jpg 304 7.196 ms - -
GET /vendor/font-awesome/fonts/fontawesome-webfont.woff2?v=4.6.3 304 1.484 ms - -
```

Comment: 500 means server error, any log in the server side?

Comment: there was no log on console. But in npm-debug I found ELIFECYCLE error.

Comment: Can you add it to the question?

Comment: life cycle error is different one. I added console log to the question. I think that is only log I cound find.

Comment: That explains the 500, good job. I'm glad to heard that. Regards.